# Forward declaration of template class in nested namespace: where should default template arguments go?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, forward-declaration

I have a forward declaration of a template class in a nested namespace

```
namespace n1
{
    namespace n2
    {
        template <typename T, typename S>
        struct A;
    }
    using n2::A;
}
```

followed by a definition, which in fact is in a different file, with stuff in between:

```
struct X { };

namespace n1
{
    namespace n2
    {
        template <typename T, typename S = X>
        struct A { };
    }
    using n2::A;
}
```

Then the following is always ok:

```
n1::n2::A <int> a;
```

but this shortcut

```
n1::A <int> a;
```

gives a compile error in clang

```
error: too few template arguments for class template 'A'
```

unless I remove the forward declaration; g++ accepts both.

clang appears to stay with the first declaration which does not include the default template argument (and I cannot include it, because I have not defined `X` yet).

There is no problem if I use a single namespace (but this is not a solution).

What am I doing wrong, or, which compiler is correct? How can the shortcut work together with the forward declaration, and the nested namespace? I need all of them.

Forward-declaring `X` + default argument for S of course works, but would be too tedious (there are dozens of them actually, and the whole file structure would change).

Comment: The fact that there's stuff in between and that's in a different file doesn't matter for clang. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=fd521dbdf5)

Comment: And according to [temp.param]/10, this issue is unrelated to templates, as the mechanism is defined in terms of function default arguments. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=17873283ec)

Comment: This might be a bit more complicated than I originally thought. [dcl.fct.default]/9 actually says that your code should work, but there's an [open issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1551) with the *using-declaration* where the proposed fix introduces a contradiction to this paragraph and would break your code.

Comment: I think point 3 in the proposed resolution of this issue answers the question (then, unfortunately clang is right) but also gives an idea: skip the first using-declaration in n1. Possibly make a using-declaration in another namespace to do whatever stuff is needed, and finally a using-declaration in n1 after the definition. Thanks!

Comment: @iavr see my answer below, GCC also doesn't accept it `src/main.cpp:26:17: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)` GCC ftw btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this as a most convenient workaround:

```
namespace n1
{
    namespace n2
    {
        template <typename T, typename S>
        struct A;
    }

    namespace fwd { using n2::A; }
}

// stuff on n1::fwd::A;

struct X { };

namespace n1
{
    namespace n2
    {
        template <typename T, typename S = X>
        struct A { };
    }

    using n2::A;
}
```

That is, move the first using-declaration to another namespace. Now the 'stuff' could go like this:

```
namespace n1
{
    namespace stuff
    {
        using namespace fwd;

        template <typename T>
        struct R /*...*/;

        template <typename T, typename S>
        struct R <A <T, S> > /*...*/;
    }
}
```

using `A` without any namespaces. There is only one `n1` in my project, but lots of `n2`, so moving all forward using-declarations in a single namespace `n1::fwd` is more convenient, given that I cannot just use `n1`.

Answer (score 2):

`template<class T> using myname = some::templatething<T>;`

Then you can use myname

In your case stick a `template<class T,class S=X> using A = n2::A<T,S>;` in your `n1`

Just wrote a gem of an answer related to this [Symbol not found when using template defined in a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543980/symbol-not-found-when-using-template-defined-in-a-library) there btw, have a read.

Okay it's not been ticked, so I'm gonna help some more!

**will not compile**

```
#include <iostream>

namespace n1 {
namespace n2 {
template<class U,class V> struct A;
}
template<class U,class V> using A = n2::A<U,V>;
}

static n1::A<int,int>* test;

struct X {};
namespace n1 {
namespace n2 {
template<class U,class V> struct A {};
}
template<class U,class V=X> using A = n2::A<U,V>;
}

static n1::A<int> test2;


int main(int,char**) {

    return 0;
}
```

Why? C++'s "first declaration rule"

Here's the compiler's output:

```
make all 
if ! g++ -Isrc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c++11 -g -gdwarf-2 -Wno-write-strings  -MM src/main.cpp >> build/main.o.d ; then rm build/main.o.d ; exit 1 ; fi
g++ -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c++11 -g -gdwarf-2 -Wno-write-strings  -Isrc -c src/main.cpp -o build/main.o
src/main.cpp:26:17: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
 static n1::A<int> test2;
                 ^
src/main.cpp:13:47: error: provided for ‘template<class U, class V> using A = n1::n2::A<U, V>’
 template<class U,class V> using A = n2::A<U,V>;
                                               ^
src/main.cpp:26:24: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
 static n1::A<int> test2;
                        ^
src/main.cpp:16:24: warning: ‘test’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static n1::A<int,int>* test;
                        ^
src/main.cpp:26:19: warning: ‘test2’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static n1::A<int> test2;
                   ^
make: *** [build/main.o] Error
```

Okay it's whining about unused variables, fair enough, but notice it's reference to line 13, that's because it's used the first definition default template arguments are really quite primitive and I can't quote specification at you right now. 
https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fdefault_args_for_templ_params.htm

that may offer some insight though.

Anyway notice that:

**This compiles**

```
#include <iostream>

namespace n1 {
namespace n2 {
template<class U,class V> struct A;
}
template<class U,class V> using A = n2::A<U,V>;
}

static n1::A<int,int>* test;

struct X {};
namespace n1 {
namespace n2 {
template<class U,class V> struct A {};
}
template<class U,class V=X> using B = n2::A<U,V>;
}

static n1::B<int> test2;


int main(int,char**) {

    return 0;
}
```

Because B has no prior definition.

**Build output**

```
make all 
if ! g++ -Isrc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c++11 -g -gdwarf-2 -Wno-write-strings  -MM src/main.cpp >> build/main.o.d ; then rm build/main.o.d ; exit 1 ; fi
g++ -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c++11 -g -gdwarf-2 -Wno-write-strings  -Isrc -c src/main.cpp -o build/main.o
src/main.cpp:16:24: warning: ‘test’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static n1::A<int,int>* test;
                        ^
src/main.cpp:26:19: warning: ‘test2’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static n1::B<int> test2;
                   ^
g++  build/main.o  -o a.out
```

See, fine :)

Remember with forward declarations you can only use *s and &s (as they are of known size, fixed size infact) - oh and &&s

So you need to get that default in there right away!

Comment: Thanks, This avoids using the real A in n1 before it is complete, and uses a different *name* for the using-declaration; but I find it too complicated. For the time, I have removed the forward-declaration and declared the 'stuff' after A is complete, which I think is better design. If I really need it in the future, and as I wrote in my comment below the question, I would prefer to move the using-declaration to another namespace rather than rename it, thus avoiding template arguments altogether - I'll add an answer for that.

Comment: This issue is different from the OP's, as you're using alias templates declarations (`template < /*...*/ > using X = /*...*/;`) whereas the OP is using "simple" (non-template) alias declarations. The effects are different (both clang++ and g++ reject it), and this doesn't have to do with namespaces at all -> [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b6f6a922c2). It might have to do with the [open issue 1349](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1349).