# Symbol not found when using template defined in a library

Tags: c++, xcode, xmp

I'm trying to use the adobe xmp library in an iOS application but I'm getting link errors.  I have the appropriate headers and libraries in my path, but I'm getting link errors.  I double-checked to make sure the headers and library are on my path.  I checked the mangled names of the methods, but they aren't in the library (I checked using the `nm` command).  What am I doing wrong?

Library Header:

```
#if defined ( TXMP_STRING_TYPE )

    #include "TXMPMeta.hpp"
    #include "TXMPIterator.hpp"
    #include "TXMPUtils.hpp"
    typedef class TXMPMeta <TXMP_STRING_TYPE>     SXMPMeta;       // For client convenience.
    typedef class TXMPIterator <TXMP_STRING_TYPE> SXMPIterator;
    typedef class TXMPUtils <TXMP_STRING_TYPE>    SXMPUtils;
```

.mm file:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#define IOS_ENV
#define TXMP_STRING_TYPE string
#import "XMP.hpp"

void DoStuff()
{    
    SXMPMeta meta;
    string returnValue;
    meta.SetProperty ( kXMP_NS_PDF, "test", "{ formId: {guid} }" );
    meta.DumpObject(DumpToString, &returnValue);
}
```

Link Errors:

```
(null): "TXMPMeta<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::DumpObject(int (*)(void*, char const*, unsigned int), void*) const", referenced from:
(null): "TXMPMeta<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::TXMPMeta()", referenced from:
(null): "TXMPMeta<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::SetProperty(char const*, char const*, char const*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
(null): "TXMPMeta<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::~TXMPMeta()", referenced from:
(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I know it's kind of ... wrong, but man my answer is so good, and has awesome examples, would you mind broadening your question (perhaps at the bottom) so search engines might find it and stuff? I'm not sure, but it is a gem, and it's simple, it ought to explain it to people who (rightly) fear linker errors.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  The additional information you provided is available elsewhere on SO, so this question is really more about getting the adobe xmp library working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically what's happened is that you only have the definitions in the headers
if I say

`template<class T> T something(T);` somewhere, that tells the compiler "trust me bro, it exists, leave it to the linker"

and it adds the symbol to the object file as if it did exist. Because it can see the prototype it knows how much stack space, what type it returns and such, so it just sets it up so the linker can just come along and put the address of the function in.

BUT in your case there is no address. You /MUST/ have the template definition (not just declaration) in the same file so the compiler can create one (with weak linkage) so here it's assumed they exist, but no where does it actually stamp out this class from a template, so the linker doesn't find it, hence the error.

Will fluff out my answer now, hope this helps.

Addendum 1:

```
template<class T> void output(T&);

int main(int,char**) {
    int x = 5;
    output(x);
    return 0;
}
```

This will compile but **NOT** link.

Output:

```
if ! g++ -Isrc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c++11 -g -gdwarf-2 -Wno-write-strings  -MM src/main.cpp >> build/main.o.d ; then rm build/main.o.d ; exit 1 ; fi
g++ -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c++11 -g -gdwarf-2 -Wno-write-strings  -Isrc -c src/main.cpp -o build/main.o
g++  build/main.o  -o a.out
build/main.o: In function `main':
(my home)/src/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `void output<int>(int&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [a.out] Error 1
```

(I hijacked an open projet for this hence the names)

As you can see the compile command works fine (the one that ends in -o build/main.o) because we tell it "look this function exists"

So in the object file it says to the linker (in some "name managled form" to keep the templates) "put the location in memory of void output(int&); here" the linker can't find it.

**Compiles and links**

```
#include <iostream>
template<class T> void output(T&);

int main(int,char**) {
    int x = 5;
    output(x);
    return 0;
}

template<class T> void output(T& what) {
    std::cout<<what<<"\n";
    std::cout.flush();
}
```

Notice line 2, we tell it "there exists a function, a template in T called output, that returns nothing and takes a T reference", that means it can use it in the main function (remember when it's parsing the main function it hasn't seen the definition of output yet, it has just been told it exists), the linker then fixes that. 'though modern compilers are much much smarter (because we have more ram :) ) and rape the structure of your code, link-time-optimisation does this even more, but this is how it used to work, and how it can be considered to work these days.

Output:

```
make all 
if ! g++ -Isrc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c++11 -g -gdwarf-2 -Wno-write-strings  -MM src/main.cpp >> build/main.o.d ; then rm build/main.o.d ; exit 1 ; fi
g++ -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c++11 -g -gdwarf-2 -Wno-write-strings  -Isrc -c src/main.cpp -o build/main.o
g++  build/main.o  -o a.out
```

As you can see it compiled fine and linked fine.

**Multiple files without include as proof of this**

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

int TrustMeCompilerIExist();

int main(int,char**) {
    std::cout<<TrustMeCompilerIExist();
    std::cout.flush();
    return 0;
}
```

**proof.cpp**

```
int TrustMeCompilerIExist() {
    return 5;
}
```

**Compile and link**

```
make all 
if ! g++ -Isrc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c++11 -g -gdwarf-2 -Wno-write-strings  -MM src/main.cpp >> build/main.o.d ; then rm build/main.o.d ; exit 1 ; fi
g++ -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c++11 -g -gdwarf-2 -Wno-write-strings  -Isrc -c src/main.cpp -o build/main.o
if ! g++ -Isrc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c++11 -g -gdwarf-2 -Wno-write-strings  -MM src/proof.cpp >> build/proof.o.d ; then rm build/proof.o.d ; exit 1 ; fi
g++ -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c++11 -g -gdwarf-2 -Wno-write-strings  -Isrc -c src/proof.cpp -o build/proof.o
g++  build/main.o build/proof.o  -o a.out
```

(Outputs 5)

Remember #include LITERALLY dumps a file where it says "#include" (+ some other macros that adjust line numbers) this is called a translation unit. Rather than using a header file to contain "int TrustMeCompilerIExist();" which declares that the function exists (but the compiler again doesn't know where it is, the code inside of it, just that it exists) I repeated myself.

Lets look at proof.o

**command**

```
objdump proof.o -t
```

**output**

```
proof.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 proof.cpp
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_info    0000000000000000 .debug_info
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_abbrev  0000000000000000 .debug_abbrev
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_aranges 0000000000000000 .debug_aranges
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_line    0000000000000000 .debug_line
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_str 0000000000000000 .debug_str
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack    0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame  0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment   0000000000000000 .comment
0000000000000000 g     F .text  0000000000000006 _Z21TrustMeCompilerIExistv
```

Right at the bottom there, there's a function, at offset 6 into the file, with debugging information, (the g is global though) you can see it's called _Z (this is why _ is reserved for some things, I forget what exactly... but it's to do with this) and Z is "integer", 21 is the name length, and after the name, the v is "void" the return type.

The zeros at the start btw are the section number, remember binaries can be HUGE.

**Disassembly**
running:

`objdump proof.o -S` gives

```
proof.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_Z21TrustMeCompilerIExistv>:


int TrustMeCompilerIExist() {
    return 5;
}
   0:   b8 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%eax
   5:   c3                      retq
```

Because I have -g you can see it put the code that the assembly relates to (it makes more sense with bigger functions, it shows you what the following instructions until the next code block actually do) that wouldn't normally be there.

**main.o**

Here's the symbol table, obtained the same way as the above:

```
objdump main.o -t

main.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 main.cpp
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l    d  .text.startup  0000000000000000 .text.startup
0000000000000030 l     F .text.startup  0000000000000026 _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
0000000000000000 l     O .bss   0000000000000001 _ZStL8__ioinit
0000000000000000 l    d  .init_array    0000000000000000 .init_array
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_info    0000000000000000 .debug_info
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_abbrev  0000000000000000 .debug_abbrev
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_loc 0000000000000000 .debug_loc
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_aranges 0000000000000000 .debug_aranges
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_ranges  0000000000000000 .debug_ranges
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_line    0000000000000000 .debug_line
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_str 0000000000000000 .debug_str
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack    0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame  0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment   0000000000000000 .comment
0000000000000000 g     F .text.startup  0000000000000026 main
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _Z21TrustMeCompilerIExistv
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _ZSt4cout
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _ZNSolsEi
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _ZNSo5flushEv
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 .hidden __dso_handle
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 __cxa_atexit
```

See how it says undefined, that's because it doesn't know where it is, it just knows it exists (along with the standard lib stuff, which the linker will find itself)

**In closing**
USE HEADER GUARDS and with templates put #include file.cpp at the bottom BEFORE the closing header guard. that way you can include header files as usual :)

Comment: Ah, right you are.  For some reason I assumed one of the included headers defined the class somewhere, but I was missing the `#import "XMP.incl_cpp"` line!

Comment: @mydogisbox Finished! Did you get all of that, does it help? Also see the bottom for what I do with my templates :)

Comment: If I were to write a template class, your point at the bottom would be helpful.  Sadly this library isn't something I own, so I can't fix it.

Comment: These types of answers make StackOverflow useful! Great answer! +1!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is present in ever sample that comes with **XMP SDK Toolkit**.Clients must compile XMP.incl_cpp to ensure that all client-side glue code is generated. Do this by including it in exactly one of your source files.

For your ready reference I am pasting below a more detailed explanation present in section **Template classes and accessing the API** of XMPProgrammersGuide.pdf that comes with **XMP SDK Toolkit**

**Template classes and accessing the API**

The full client API is defined and documented in the TXMP*.hpp header files. The TXMP* classes are C++ template classes that must be instantiated with a string class such as std::string, which is used to return text strings for property values, serialized XMP, and so on.  To allow your code to access the entire XMP API you must:

Provide a string class such as std::string to instantiate the template classes.

Provide access to XMPCore and XMPFiles by including the necessary defines and headers. To do this, add the necessary define and includes directives to your source code so that all necessary code is incorporated into the build:

```
#include <string>
#define XMP_INCLUDE_XMPFILES 1 //if using XMPFiles
#define TXMP_STRING_TYPE std::string
#include "XMP.hpp"
```

The SDK provides complete reference documentation for the template classes, but the templates must be instantiated for use. You can read the header files (TXMPMeta.hpp and so on) for information, but do not include them directly in your code. There is one overall header file, XMP.hpp, which is the only one that C++ clients should include using the #include directive. Read the instructions in this file for instantiating the template classes. When you have done this, the API is available through the concrete classes named SXMP*; that is,  SXMPMeta, SXMPUtils, SXMPIterator, and SXMPFiles. This document refers to the SXMP* classes, which you can instantiate and which provide static functions.

Clients must compile XMP.incl_cpp to ensure that all client-side glue code is generated. Do this by including it in exactly one of your source files. 
Read XMP_Const.h for detailed information about types and constants for namespace URIs and option flags.

Comment: Sadly there are no samples for iOS, so it's difficult to make inferences about what should/shouldn't be the same as the samples.  I probably should have read the documentation more closely.

Comment: You seem to have some knowledge of the library.  Is there something else wrong with my code above?  Now that it compiles, it throws an exception on the set property method and likewise if I try to instantiate an `SXMPMeta` object like in the samples with `SXMPMeta meta ( kNewlineRDF, kXMP_UseNullTermination );` (the exception is then thrown in the constructor).

Comment: Both exceptions happen in the `XMP_AutoMutex` constructor.

Comment: On second thought, I'll just post this question to the adobe developer center.

Comment: Probably you haven't called the SXMPMeta::Initialize() or SXMPMeta::Initialise() as library init calls for **XMPCore** and **XMPFiles** libs respectively.If you are using both libs you have to call both of them.For a quick response , its a good idea to post the questions to adobe developer center http://forums.adobe.com/community/design_development/xmp_sdk .You can also start a new discussion on XMP SDK by sending a mail to discussions-community-design_development-xmp_sdk@mail.forums.adobe.com.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was missing `SXMPMeta::Initialize()`.  `XMPFiles` isn't supported for iOS.