# uable to solve undefined reference to symbol with cmake

Tags: c++, linker, cmake

I was presented with the following error when trying to make a program i downloaded.

> CMakeFiles/ptcloud_vslam_node.dir/src/nodes/ptcloud_vslam_node.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pcl::console::print(pcl::console::VERBOSITY_LEVEL, char const*, ...)'
>
> /usr/bin/ld: note: 'pcl::console::print(pcl::console::VERBOSITY_LEVEL, char const*, ...)' is defined in DSO /opt/ros/groovy/lib/libpcl_common.so.1.6 so try adding it to the linker 
>   command line
>
> /opt/ros/groovy/lib/libpcl_common.so.1.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation

I tried adding the following in my cmake file

```
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libpcl_common.so.1.6)
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ptcloud_vslam_node libpcl_common.so.1.6)
```

but I was given the following error while running cmake

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:51 (TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES):
>     Cannot specify link libraries for target "ptcloud_vslam_node" which is not
>     built by this project.

What modification should I make to my cmake file in other to fix the linking error?

Many Thanks

Comment: You can only specify libs to link to on an actual target that's is already recognized by CMake when the function is called. Is ptcloud_vslam_node correctly specified before TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES?

Comment: The following is defined after TARGET_LINK_LIB       
`# stereo & ptcloud VSLAM as a ROS node
rosbuild_add_executable(ptcloud_vslam_node src/nodes/ptcloud_vslam_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ptcloud_vslam_node vo ${Boost_LIBRARIES})`

Is this the specification you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

It says "Link directories" but you are passing it an actual library, the error is unhappy because for some reason it wants to build `ptcloud_vslam_node`, it doesn't seem to realise that you are trying to specify it.

Please post more information and add a comment to this answer, and I'll check back.

[Symbol not found when using template defined in a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543980/symbol-not-found-when-using-template-defined-in-a-library/18544093#18544093)

That will explain how linking works, then you'll perhaps better understand errors.

Comment: Ah what a silly mistake, i corrected the "Link Directories" to point to a directory.
But the same error still persist. How should I go about configuring the  cmake file to have the linker link with the above said lib?

Comment: I have located the reason which was causing the "Cannot specify link libraries for target" error. It seems that the original created had already specified a **TARGET_LINK_LIBRARY** for `ptcloud_vslam_node`